# Кто декодирует строку запроса, ЯП или браузер?

Tags: php, get

Всем привет.

Заметил такую штуку, что если я передаю строку через `GET`:

```
?server=Super Server + GF -
```

Я в php вывожу значение `$_GET['server']`, и получаю:

```
Super Server   GF -
```

Получается, что php сам делает `urldecode()`, при выводе `$_GET`, и как положено заменяет `+` на пробел.

Но вот вопрос, это настройка какая - то, или особенность php? Или это настраивается в Apache?

Просто сейчас, что бы мне передать в `GET` знак `+` - мне нужно через JS сделать:

```
encodeURIComponent('Super Server + GF -')// Super%20Server%20%2B%20GF%20-
```

И только в таком случае, php мне выведет:

```
Super Server + GF -
```

Если передать в `GET`:

```
&test=a+a
```

При выводе мы получим:

```
echo $_GET['test'];//a a
echo urldecode( $_GET['test'] );//a a
```

Получается, что php все-таки декодирует строку запроса...

И я вот не понимаю, это браузер декодирует строку и передает её на сервер, или сервер декодирует строку?

Comment: php тут не причем, браузер посылает запрос на сервер. К тому же вы же посмотрите, вы делаете `encodeURIComponent` из js (то есть из браузера) - прям из коробки. Так-же и с юникодом, браузер шлет юникод - причем гарантию на то, что так делают все браузеры дать нельзя.

Comment: за это и беспокоюсь, что все браузеры должны работать по стардарту, но это не дает гаратнии того что так и есть. Поэтому я даже не знаю как быть, пока что буду без urldecode работать..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервер не кодирует `GET, POST, PUT, etc...` запросы, мы собираем и в ручную, а после этого браузер формирует тело запроса, автоматически добавляет нужные заголовки и посылает на сервер.
Нам нужно кодировать параметры самим.

В вашем случае когда вы отправляете не кодированную строку вида:

```
?server=Super Server + GF -
```

Браузер видит `+` и заменяет на пробел, так как все пробелы это `+`, а `+`-пробел или `%20`.
По этому если на сервере, сделать так:

```
urlencode($_GET['server]);
```

Мы получим:

```
Super+Server+++GF+-
```

А если так:

```
rawurlencode($_GET['server']);
```

Мы получим:

```
Super%20Server%20%20%20GF%20-
```

А если отправляем так:

```
encodeURIComponent('Super Server + GF -')
```

То уже нужно сделать так:

```
rawurldecode($_GET['server'])
```

Получаем:

```
Super Server + GF -
```

То, что нам было нужно, а вообще советую более детально изучить спецификацию кодирование и декодирование строк.

А так-же почитайте в чем отличие между js `encodeURI` и `encodeURIComponent`, а так-же в php `urldecode` и `rawurldecode`.